# In python, how to sort list by frequency of elements

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-itertools

I have a list of elements: `[ 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8 ]` and need to sort it by the frequency of elements to get this: `[ 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8 ]` of several elements have the same frequency sort them by value. Can you find any shorter way than this?

```
import collections
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

def freq_sort(arr):
    counter=collections.Counter(arr)
    com = sorted(counter.most_common(), key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True)
    com = map(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], com)
    return [item for sublist in com for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchance.

Comment: Define 'shorter'. The answer proposed by Darth Kotik is shorter in terms of characters, but it needless executes one additional loop per unique element in the list. As a side note it's worth noting that your given solution creates problems if used on a list that has mutable elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> old_list = [ 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8 ]
new_list = sorted(old_list, key = old_list.count, reverse=True)
>>> new_list
[6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8]
```

Comment: This doesn't sort by value when the counts are equal. Also having list.count as the key function is not very efficient (makes the sort O(N*N))

Comment: Can you do some benchmarking to show how execution time is compared to the solution in question?

Comment: Though you'd want to memoize `old_list.count` if `old_list`'s length is appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

The collections.Counter method most_common() does almost what you want. It returns the pairs (value, frequency) sorted by frequency. You require your list to be sorted by value as well; the method does not guarantee it (the spec says that when the frequencies are the same, the order of values is arbitrary). So we have to pass it to the sorted() function.

Here's the code:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [ 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8 ]
c = Counter(l)
sc = sorted(c.most_common(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])) # sorting happens here
sl = [([v] * n) for (v, n) in sc]
ss = sum(sl, [])
print(ss)
```

This method has an advantage over other methods that it runs in time only O(m log m) where m is a number of distinct values in l. Other methods will run in time O(n log n) where n is a length o l, that is always greater or equal to the number of distinct values. You will basically be using Bucket Sort algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Doing two sorts is often faster than the extra overhead of a lambda function. This works because Python's sort is stable

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = [ 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8 ]
>>> c = Counter(L)
>>> sorted(sorted(L), key=c.get, reverse=True)
[6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8]
```

The second sort is very fast since the data is now already partially sorted which timsort excels at.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit shorter in terms of lines count and sorts first by count and then by value:

```
import collections
arr = [ 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 8 ]
counter = collections.Counter(arr)
sorted( arr, key=lambda x: (counter[x], x), reverse=True )
```

Comment: Should be `(counter[x], -x)` to get the correct order